# Closed points of $\mathbb{Q}(t) \otimes_\mathbb{Q} \mathbb{C}$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

According to an exercise in Ravi's notes, closed points of $\mathbb{Q}(t) \otimes_\mathbb{Q} \mathbb{C}$ are supposed to be in "natural" bijection with the transcendental complex numbers.

But I am confused about the following train of (my) thought:

We have a map from $\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C} (t)$ (the obvious one), and also a map from $\mathbb{Q} (t) \to \mathbb{C} (t)$. Together these maps induce a map from $\mathbb{Q}(t) \otimes_\mathbb{Q} \mathbb{C}$ to $\mathbb{C}(t)$, which appears to be surjective because the image is a field that includes $\mathbb{C}$ and $t$. Thus we have a surjective map onto a field, and hence this corresponds to a closed point of $\mathbb{Q}(t) \otimes_\mathbb{Q} \mathbb{C}$.

If this reasoning is correct, then I am very confused - what transcendental element of $\mathbb{C} $ does this closed point correspond to?

Edit: My confusion is resolved. Of course the image of the tensor product is not a field, because the tensor product is not a field.

Comment: It seems to me that $\mathbb{Q}(t) \otimes_\mathbb{Q} \mathbb{C}$ can be embedded into $\mathbb C(t)$. I don't know how did you find a surjection.

Comment: @user26857 Oh, I am being silly. The image is of course not a field. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$\mathbb{Q}(t) \otimes_\mathbb{Q} \mathbb{C}\simeq S^{-1}\mathbb C[t]$, where $S=\mathbb Q[t]-\{0\}$. Thus the maximal ideals of your ring are of the form $S^{-1}(t-a)$ with $(t-a)\cap S=\emptyset$. The condition $(t-a)\cap S=\emptyset$ is equivalent to $a$ transcendental over $\mathbb Q$.

Comment: A brilliant answer: +1. @AreaMan You should definitely accept this answer: you won't get a better one !